# Can I use an IP Address when signing up for google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a CMS built with angular that allows users to create a basic website and then register an available domain to use.  For example, if I register `example.com`, when a user goes to `example.com`, it pulls data down and renders content for that site.  `example2.com` can also be created and if that is accessed, it pulls content for that site.

The problem I have is when signing up for Google analytics, it asks for a website URL, but in my case it varies, so can I use an IP address? or is there another option as well?

Comment: "it varies" as in there are multiple domains?   I'd say just pick one of them.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller - They are different websites.  I want to know who came went to example.com as opposed to example2.com

Comment: Then create a setting in the CMS for each domain allowing the user to input their Google Analytics tracking id or snippet and treat each domain separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you want to limit your tracking code to just one domain it should be fine to use it in a different domain. Just make sure you use auto as a parameter:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
```

Specifying **auto** enables automatic cookie domain configuration, which tells analytics.js to automatically determine the best cookie domain to use.

[Reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookies-user-id)

Comment: OK Thanks, When I signed up, I put the IP address for the Website URL (will it use this for anything?).  I did notice the script has auto in it already.